# How to implement non-blocking IO input in embedded baremetal systems?

Tags: uart, bare-metal, soc

I'm working on CycloneVsoc(Cortex-A9 duel core) with a baremetal system with ARMCC.
For now the system uses two cores and each core runs the same FPGA timer interrupt(50us) for each.
The system is debuged by ARMDS IDE and PuTTY.

Now I want to implement a non-blocking scanf function. There are many answers for Linux/Windows, but few of them is for the baremetal system.

So I have a basic idea:
I can set a push button as an interrupt,which has a lower priority than my FPGA timer IRQ.

The working flow is as shown IN THE USER VIEW:
PB IRQ(Start the scan) ----> User input on Terminal -----> Press"ENTER" IRQ ----> Put data into the UART FIFO  -----> read the UART FIFO -----> check -----> transfer to what I want.

To fulfill this I have some questions:

1. Is that realistic? or is there other easier solutions?
2. How to set the Uart IRQ from terminal ?
3. How to set the "ENTER" as a interrupt ?

Thank you

Comment: This is an architecture question.  You are asking for data structures to communicate between an IRQ and a mainline.  You need the IRQ to scan for 'Enter'.  Setup a ring buffer for the IRQ to write to and the main line to read from.  The IRQ will set a variable of the last 'ENTER' index.  You need the mainline to read to this index and read a string to that position, freeing the data for the IRQ.  The ring buffer needs to be sized to the maximum buffer size.  You could know by baud rate, what is safe.

Comment: Your title question doesn't make sense. Does your "*baremetal system*" have any framework for multiple processes/tasks and a scheduler? BTW non-blocking schemes tend to under-utilize the CPU unless you put extra effort to perform useful processing while waiting. Your "*working flow*" is confusing because it seems to blend human actions, HW functionality, and SW actions in one nonsensical and unrealistic linear sequence. Like the worst baremetal implementations, you seem to make no distinction between a driver layer versus an application layer.

Comment: "*Now I want to implement a ... scanf function.*" - But what you confusing seem to describe is simply a 'read a line of input'. Seems like you have not considered what needs to happen if something like a `backspace` key/character is typed. IOW perhaps there needs to be a code separation (i.e. layering) of (a) simply handling the UART to receive & buffer the input from (b) a lexical scan for special/control characters.